# How to plan a ride by several buses?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computer-science, applications

Given

- a source location and a destination location, and
- an acceptable range of departure times, or an acceptable range of arrival times, and
- a schedule of available bus routes (e.g. http://www.tcatbus.com/ride/),

you would like to take bus(es) to go from the source to the destination, either start within the range of departure times, or arrive within the range of arrival times.

1. **Mathematically,** how do you plan a trip, and list two or three
   optional plans according to their travel time lengths?

   It is an optimization problem. Can we model it as a graph
   optimization problem, a dynamic programming problem, or ..., so that
   we can solve it using algorithms for the specific optimization
   problems?

   For example, there is a trip planner (http://tcat.nextinsight.com/),
   and ways to implement such a trip planner is what I am interested
   in.
2. On the other hand, **empirically**, how does an intelligent human
   (who hasn't learn mathematical optimization) make a trip plan? You may use some tools that are available at http://www.tcatbus.com/ride/,
   such as you can look up the schedule (stops and times) of a specific route, and you can also look up
   which routes stop at a specific stop and when.

Thanks.

Comment: It's basically a graph reachability problem, with the nodes being pairs of locations and times. (Construct one node for each bus stop at each time a bus arrives or departs from it).

Comment: @Henning: Thanks! How do you model the schedules of bus routes into the graph?

Comment: Basically with an edge for each individual bus that goes from one stop to another, and an edge from earlier to later times that the same stop (coresponding to waiting there). When one bus follows a route with $n$ stops, you have a trade-off between making $\binom n2$ edges (one for each possible journey with that bus), or $n-1$ internal nodes (corresponding intuitively to "be on the bus between these two neighboring stops") and $3$ edges for each stop, corresponding to boarding, alighting and staying on the bus past the stop.

Comment: The best trade-off between those choices will depend on implementation details in your algorithm. It will probably be advantageous to generate the graph lazily from a more compact timetable representation so you don't need to generate parts of the graph that are not reachable anyway.